# SOQL query to get the column which is not in the group by clause

Tags: apex, soql

Lets say the below records exist in the CampaignMember table:

```
+------+------------+--------+-------------+
| Id   | CampaignId | LeadId | CreatedDate |
+------+------------+--------+-------------+
| 8881 | 7771       | 6661   | 8/18/15     |
| 8882 | 7772       | 6661   | 8/19/15     |
| 8883 | 7773       | 6662   | 8/15/15     |
| 8884 | 7774       | 6662   | 8/14/15     |
+------+------------+--------+-------------+
```

And I want to get the latest campaign for each Lead, output I want is like below:

```
+--------+------------+
| LeadId | CampaignId |
+--------+------------+
|   6661 |       7772 |
|   6662 |       7773 |
+--------+------------+
```

In SQL, I could do like this :

```
SELECT leadid, 
       campaignid 
FROM   campaignmember 
WHERE  ( 
                SELECT   Max(createddate) AS cd, 
                         leadid 
                FROM     campaignmember 
                GROUP BY leadid) x 
WHERE  createddate = x.cd 
AND    leadid=x.leadid
```

But How do I do the same in SOQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve the desired result with SOQL alone.  You will need some additional processing in apex and/or perform multiple queries.

For a single query, you should be able to do:

```
List<Lead> leads = [
    SELECT Id, 
        (SELECT LeadId, CampaignId 
         FROM CampaignMembers 
         ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC 
         LIMIT 1)
    FROM Lead
    WHERE Id IN (SELECT LeadId FROM CampaignMember)
    ORDER BY Id];

List<CampaignMember> campaignMembers = new List<CampaignMember>();
for (Lead l : leads) {
    campaignMembers.addAll(l.CampaignMembers);
}
```

However, be aware that this will likely encounter SOQL governor limits if there are a large number of Leads.  You should try to reduce the Leads to either a known list of Leads, restrict the Campaign Members to a given date range or specific Campaigns, and anything else specific to your development to reduce the Lead count.

Comment: Thomas,  I tried your code and this code is giving me the leadId and the associated most recent Campaign:  `Map<Id,Lead> leadIdMapObj = new Map<Id,Lead>([SELECT Id,
                            (SELECT Id,
                            CampaignId,LeadId,CreatedDate,Campaign.Name FROM
                            CampaignMembers ORDER BY CreatedDate) FROM Lead
                            WHERE Id IN ('6661',6662')]);`